# Zend Action helper

Tags: zend-framework

I am learning how to use Zend framework and realise that the action helper is something that would be useful. 
I have set up a default installation of Zend on my machine, but I dont know where the helper file needs to go, what I need to put in the bootstrap file and how I use it. Can anyone point me in the right direction please - the ZF user guide is not to clear to me.

Thanks
John

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Two thoughts for where to place your custom action-helpers:

1. In a separate, custom library
2. In the folder `application/controllers/helpers`

These ideas are not exclusive. Functionality that is general enough to work in multiple  projects should probably be pulled into a separate library. But for functionality that is application-specific, there is an argument that it could be somewhere in the `application` folder.

@Jurian has already described the "separate-library" approach. For app-specific helpers, you can do as follows:

For a helper called myHelper, create a class `Application_Controller_Helper_MyHelper` in the file `application/controllers/helpers/MyHelper.php`. In `Bootstrap`, you have something like:

```
protected function _initAutoload()
{
    $autoloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
        'namespace' => 'Application',
        'basePath'  => APPLICATION_PATH,
    ));

    Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addPath(
        APPLICATION_PATH . '/controllers/helpers', 
        'Application_Controller_Helper_');

    return $autoloader;
}
```

Then your helper can be invoked in a controller by using:

```
$this->_helper->myHelper;
```

As you can see, this presumes you are using appNamespace 'Application'. If not, you can (must!) modify your class names to accommodate your circumstance.

Cheers!

Comment: Small note, since you're starting the path with `APPLICATION_PATH`, your '/application/controllers/helpers' should be just '/controllers/helpers' without `/application` at the start. Also I've been finding that the prefix `'Application_Controller_Helper_'` doesn't have to necessarily match the physical folder structure. If you set the prefix (second param) as `Blabla_`, as long as the action helper classes all start with just `Blabla_Helpername` it works. This helps cut down the class names if that's something that matters to you. and of course +1 for a good answer.

Comment: D'oh! You're right: the `application` path is already included in APPLICATION_PATH. Sorry. Correcting my answer. Also, of course you are right: since you can define the mapping in the `addPath()` call, you can use nearly any classnames you want. I tend to mimic the Zend structure in my own library namespace, even if they are a little longer. For example, I usually name a plugin as `My_Controller_Plugin_SomePlugin`, but I often see others use something like `My_Plugin_SomePlugin`. As you observe, either way works as long as your `addPath()` call maps it correctly. Thanks and cheers! ;-)

Answer (score 6):

You can place action helpers in your own library. Besides library/Zend where all the Zend stuff is around, you can create a library/MyLibrary folder (MyLibrary is arbitrary chosen) and put the action helpers there.

A good place is the library/MyLibrary/Controller/Action/Helper folder you need to create and place your action helper there (i.e. Navigation.php). In this file, create the class `MyLibrary_Controller_Action_Helper_Navigation`.

The next step is to add the action helper to the HelperBroker of the Zend Framework during bootstrap. Therefore, create a new method in your Bootstrap.php file and add this function:

```
protected function _initActionHelpers ()
{
    Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper(
        new MyLibrary_Controller_Action_Helper_Navigation()
    );
}
```

One last remark is you need to configure the use of this library by adding this rule to your application.ini:

```
autoLoaderNameSpaces[] = "MyLibrary_"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this through your `application.ini` file like so

```
resources.view[] =
resources.view.helperPath.Default_View_Helper_ = APPLICATION_PATH "/views/helpers/"
```

Then in your `views/helpers` path you can create a file like `Time.php`. This file would contain the following code:

```
<?php

class Default_View_Helper_Time extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function time()
    {
        $date = new Zend_Date();

        return $date->get(Zend_Date::TIME_MEDIUM);
    }
}

?>
```

To use this in your view scripts you would use

```
<?=$this->time()?>
```

Which would display the current time using your new `View_Helper`

Comment: hi how can i call view helper on my application controller helper..?

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid having to register your action helper namespace and path within the `Bootstrap.php` by declaring them in the `application.ini` instead like so:

```
resources.frontController.actionHelperPaths.My_Controller_Action_Helper = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers/helpers"
```

Simply replace `My_Controller_Action_Helper` with your desired namespace, and modify the helpers directory path accordingly.

The helper can be initialized the same way:

```
$this->_helper->myHelper;
```

As mentioned by the docs, registering the prefix or path of the helpers is usually preferred because helpers would not be initialized until they are called like in the snippet above.

> Of course, instantiating and passing helpers to the broker is a bit
>   time and resource intensive, so two methods exists to automate things
>   slightly: addPrefix() and addPath().

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.loader.pluginloader.html

Adding the config entry to the `application.ini` follows the same suggested pattern.